# What happens if I "thumbs down" a song I actually like, but don't want to hear anymore?

Tags: pandora

Sometimes, Pandora plays songs that have been grossly overplayed and I am just sick of hearing. I assumed that skipping the song would be indicative of this, but it doesn't seem to reduce the frequency at which Pandora plays these songs. However, I'm afraid that if I give the song a thumbs down, Pandora will factor it in with song types that I don't want to hear as opposed to specific songs that I don't want to hear.

Is there a way to make it clear to Pandora that I only want to stop hearing a particular song, but that I still like similar music?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mouse over the album cover image, and choose the upward facing triangle, you can select "I'm tired of this song". Pandora will then not play it for a while.

At one point, "a while" meant one month (?), but it doesn't seem to say any more.